# How does the world bank app achieve this kind of pop up?

Tags: javascript, html

The world bank website has a cool application for visualising data. I have provided a link to the application at the bottom of this post.

For each of the statistical areas there is a light grey magnifying glass in the top right hand corner and once click it loads kind of a transparent fullscreen pop up which you can also hide when done.

Does anyone know what API or method they used to achieve this? Or even point me in the right direction of how to do something similar?

http://data.worldbank.org/country/australia

Answer (score 3):

It's being done using JavaScript. The data presented in the overlays is already loaded with the page, but it's hidden (css `display: none`). When you click the magnifying glass link, the respective div is set to `display: block`.

I don't know which overlay script they are using, but you can google for `javascript page overlay` for tutorials/examples.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can pull off that effect quite easily using jQuery, like so:

```
$("button:first").click(function() {
  $(".overlay").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$("button:last").click(function () {
  $(".overlay").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/WHEK3/2/)